# How to the numbers that start with a $ only Kotlin

Tags: kotlin, substring

I scanned a document in to kotlin and it has words, numbers, values, etc... but I only want the values that start with a $ and have 2 decimal places after the .(so the price) do I use a combination of a substring with other string parses?

Edit: I have looked into Regex and the problem I am having now is I am using this line

```
val reg = Regex("\$([0-9]*\.[0-9]*)")
```

to grab all the prices however the portion of *. is saying Invalid escape. However in other languages this works just fine.

Comment: Look up how to use Regex.

Comment: @Tenfour04 Thank you can you please check the edit

Answer (score 0):

You have to use double \ instead of single . It's because the \ is an escape character both in Regex and in Kotlin/Java strings. So when \ appears in a String, Kotlin expects it to be followed by a character that needs to be escaped. But you aren't trying to escape a String's character...you're trying to escape a Regex character. So you have to escape your backslash itself using another backslash, so the backslash is part of the computed String literal and can be understood by Regex.

You also need double \ before your dollar sign for it to behave correctly. Technically, I think it should be triple \ because $ is a special character in both Kotlin and in Regex and you want to escape it in both. However, Kotlin seems smart enough to guess what you're trying to do with a double escape if no variable name or expression follows the dollar sign. Rather than rely on that, I would use the triple escape.

```
val reg = Regex("\\\$([0-9]*\\.[0-9]*)")
```